# Add columns to summary data when drilling down into the data from dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to add specific columns into the summary data without that data showing up in the dashboard itself.

Example data set:

[image]

I would like to add 1 or 2 columns to this summary without having to add that data to the dashboard.

Is there a way to include other fields in the Summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the data to the Detail shelf. Depending on the specifics of your worksheet set up this could impact your dashboard.

Comment: Well adding to Details did cause the display to change but adding it to the tool-tip actually did exactly what I wanted :D Well kinda. The summary has the filed now but it only shows as a star. However in the full data tab when I un-select show all fields it shows each value of the column I wanted to see so this should be good enough.